# Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): 5 is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\disqueras\userlist.php on line 64

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to show all the users from my DB. I have made a Master Detail Page. In the browser is showing me the following Warning "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): 5 is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\disqueras\userlist.php on line 64" i can see the table but just showing 1 of the 6 user that i have create (2nd)

**MY QUESTION IS : WHY IS SHOWING 1 USER INSTEAD OF "ALL" AND WHAT IS THE PROBLEM WITH THE LOOP ON THE LINE 64**

LINE 64:

```
 <?php } while ($row_mediterraneo = mysql_fetch_assoc($mediterraneo));
 ?>
```

Here is all the code

```
<?php require_once('Connections/Disquera.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_Disquera, $Disquera);
$query_mediterraneo = "SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY `user`.srtName";
$mediterraneo = mysql_query($query_mediterraneo, $Disquera) or die(mysql_error());
$row_mediterraneo = mysql_fetch_assoc($mediterraneo);
$totalRows_mediterraneo = mysql_num_rows($mediterraneo);

mysql_free_result($mediterraneo);
?>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>idCounter</td>
    <td>strEmail</td>
    <td>strPassword</td>
    <td>intActive</td>
    <td>srtName</td>
    <td>srtSociety</td>
    <td>intRole</td>
    <td>srtInfo</td>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_mediterraneo['idCounter']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_mediterraneo['strEmail']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_mediterraneo['strPassword']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_mediterraneo['intActive']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_mediterraneo['srtName']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_mediterraneo['srtSociety']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_mediterraneo['intRole']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_mediterraneo['srtInfo']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_mediterraneo = mysql_fetch_assoc($mediterraneo)); ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You are trying to dereference a null pointer at line 525.

Comment: what does $mediterraneo have ?

Comment: mediterraneo is the name of the recordset i have made.

Comment: No need to see the code... we've seen it before http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Warning%3A+mysql_fetch_assoc%28%29%3A+is+not+a+valid+MySQL

Comment: mediterraneo(rescordeset) has:  SELECT *
FROM `user`
ORDER BY `user`.srtName when i test show all the users

Comment: You need to provide more context for your question if anyone has any chance of being able to help.

Comment: OK. i Upadate the question to be more specific Thaks for your help team!

Comment: Thank you Mark!, you solved the problem! Thank You again!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `mysql_free_result($mediterraneo);` before the loop: you're clearing the result set before retrieving values from it (other than the first value, which you fetch before freeing the result set), leaving nothing to fetch in the loop.

Move `mysql_free_result($mediterraneo);` to **after** your loop